# Change the default IMAP Inbox folder on Mail.app

Tags: mail.app

Ever since I started using Priority Inbox in Gmail I don't really care about my main INBOX folder on Mail.app. Is it possible to change the default INBOX folder to `[Gmail]/Important`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very old tip but I can confirm it works. There is also some useful information in the comments section with regards to this.

[Forcing the default mailbox in Mail](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020415093634882)

Apart from this hack there is no other way to do this. I am assuming the global inbox functionality is the reason not allowing you to change it.